# Git startup script error

Tags: git, git-gui

i was using Git when i tried to open a repository. That was on a shared folder between a Windows7 virtual machine and Kubuntu 13.04 as host. 
Git closed suddenly and that was in the console:

```
Error in startup script: child process exited abnormally
while executing
"exec /usr/lib/git-core/git-config --global --unset gui.recentrepo {^/home/acuellar        /MÁquinas Virtuales/CompartidaC#/BS2-BASE2\.Utils$}"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval exec $opt $cmdp $args"
(procedure "git" line 23)
invoked from within
"git config --global --unset gui.recentrepo "^$p\$""
(procedure "_unset_recentrepo" line 3)
invoked from within
"_unset_recentrepo $p"
(procedure "_get_recentrepos" line 7)
invoked from within
"_get_recentrepos"
(procedure "choose_repository::pick" line 82)
invoked from within
"choose_repository::pick"
invoked from within
"if {[catch {
            set _gitdir $env(GIT_DIR)
            set _prefix {}
            }]
    && [catch {
            # beware that from the .git dir this sets _gitdir to .
            # and _prefix t..."
(file "/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui" line 1234)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You were using *git-gui* and the Tcl stack trace there shows that it actually tried running a `git config` command which failed. You might try running that command from the repository in question and see how it responds. The directory path as reported above looks extremely wierd to me with a number of spaces appended to the "acuellar" directory name. This was evidently while selecting a repository in the initial repo selection dialog - not actually using git-gui within a repo.

Comment: I modified the ".gitconfig" document of my user account. Then i was able to run git. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by [patthotys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291641/patthoyts) worked for me, read de comments above.

Comment: add only the relevant part of reference